# CRX2Oak executing very slow

Tags: aem

After unpacking the 6.3 jar. I can find below commands takes too much time to execute.

```
java -Xmx4096m -jar AEM_6.3-author-p4502.jar -v -x crx2oak -xargs -- --load-profile segment-no-ds --disable-mmap  --exclude-paths /content/dam
```

Any Idea where I am failing. Moreover, there will be need to remove /content/dam to include assets as well. Its upgrade from 6.0 to 6.3

Thanks

Comment: any exceptions you are noticing in the logs, during the migration process?

Comment: No error, but its taking too much time.

Comment: What is the repository size?

Answer (score 0):

You could try increasing the maximum memory in the xmx parameter, if there is more available.

Maybe opt for an offline compaction before the promote (which might take even more time though)?

I would really look at the error.log and upgrade.log because if I'm not mistaken this should take about 20 minutes according to Adobe Engineering. Maybe change the logging level of crx2oak.

Other than that, I'm guessing you're on windows (because of the --disable-mmap) so it's going to be slow.